# fullCalendaring not rendering fully without a user action

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

[image: Pic - first rendering of fullCalendar]

fullCalendar only partially renders. The calendar part is rendered only when a user manually click any of the 6 buttons in the picture or if in Chrome, right button click, then click on "Inspect Element" anywhere on the screen.

In the following code, "popupDiv" is rendered on a popup dialog box. Any other html components put in this popupDiv work fine. After a button (say "today") is clicked, everything works fine.

```
<div id="popupDiv">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                  header: {
                      left: 'prev,next today',
                      center: 'title',
                      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                  },
                  lazyFetching: false,
                  editable: false,
                  allDayDefault: false,
                  events: '/Home/GetCalendarData',

                  eventMouseover: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {

                  },

                  eventMouseout: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {

                  }

              });
</script>
```

Comment: If the dialog is invisible at the time you call FullCalendar, the calendar would not be rendered because it needs the width and height to adjust the layout. You can either delay the call to invoke FullCalendar, or [force a re-render](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/) when the dialog becomes visible.

Comment: Yes it needed a call to $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render') after popup that contained fullCalendar div.